# MVC 5, Create Dynamic Pages/Views From DataBase

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working on building a simple website.
First time working with WEB technology.
I'm interested in building a website that is quite similar to 9Gag.com.
I can't manage to figure out how they create links and pages for each and every post that they have. I've been looking for a while but I can't seem to find the answer.
I would love if you guys could give me a hint or something.
Basically I just want to create dynamic pages for each post.
Thank you for your knowledge.

Comment: what kind of dynamic page??? do they share any similarity??

Comment: Yeah they do, they can include comments and number of likes, and a picture or a video of some sort for example: http://9gag.com/gag/anXj2O0 you can see that every gag has it's own "page" and those are generated for each and every post

Comment: Most likely that they have some sort of template in the view with ID, and then just render them based on ID. if you want to store the entire page in the sql then you are not really using MVC but simply modifiable static pages

Answer (score 0):

It looks like every item on that site has similar page layout and a URL in the form of `/gag/[id]`. That's about the simplest thing in the world to create. If you're struggling with that, you need to just spend some time going through the [ASP.NET MVC tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc). The only slightly complex part is that instead of some numeric id or a guid, they're using an alphanumeric id like you typically see in short URLs. That's purely stylistic though.

Comment: Yeah the short URL is not a problem, I will browse the MVC Tutorials once again but do you know where I should look? I mean does such a pattern has a specific name or something?

Comment: It's not so much a pattern as just making basic web site that utilizes data from some sort of persistent storage backend. In other words, just a basic detail view.